# Generating the image on the screen in IOS Simulator

Tags: ios, swift

so what I currently wish to accomplish is for an image to be printed on the background of the IOS simulator screen, so inside of my viewDidLoad, I have this

`var img = UIImage(named: "paper.jpg")`

This can create the image variable, but I haven't found how to display it on the screen yet. It may seem like a trivial problem, but I haven't found any documentation on this online after searching for awhile. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the [`UIColor` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIColor_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIColor/initWithPatternImage:).

In Swift, you have to call a convenience initializer. This is because in Swift, all Objective-C class methods which return an instance of their class become convenience initializers.

Here's how it looks in Swift:

```
 self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "paper.jpg"))
```

`+ (UIColor *)colorWithPatternImage:(UIImage *)image` returns a `UIColor` instance, so it will become a convenience initializer in Swift. Similarly, `UIImage imageNamed:` becomes `init(patternImage image: UIImage!)`.

since this is the marked answer, I felt the need to add a bit more code for completion.

as @senior has posted in his answer another way to add an image to your background is by the use of adding a `UIImageView` as a subview like so:

```
let img = UIImage(named: "paper.jpg")
let imgView = UIImageView(image: img)
self.view.addSubview(imgView)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add your image to an ImageView and add this to the current view as a subview,

```
let img = UIImage(named: "paper.jpg")
let imgView = UIImageView(image: img)
self.view.addSubview(imgView)
```